# C# dynamic conversion through cast operator

Tags: c#, casting

I have some code that I have no control of. This code accepts an object parameter and attempts to cast it to a type known at compile time like this:

```
KnownType item = (KnownType) parameter;
```

Is it possible in C# to design a custom class `MyClass` (not derived from KnownType) that can be passed as parameter to the above code and be converted to `KnownType` by the above code, provided that `MyClass` can convert itself to `KnownType` using its member method:

```
protected KnownType ConvertToKnownType()
{
    // conversion code goes here
}
```

I have tried to implement a custom conversion operator like this:

```
public static implicit operator KnownType(MyClass source)
{
    KnownType result;
    // conversion goes here
    return result;
}
```

but it didn't work (it was not used). Am I right to assume that the cast operator only works when the source type, target type and conversion operators are known at compile time?

Edit:
I initially didn't provide more details about the code doing the conversion because I think it is irrelevant and because I am mainly interested in the way the cast operator is implemented, i.e. does it take look at the runtime type to find an appropriate converter or is the decision made at compile time?

To clear things out, `KnownType` is in fact `DataRowView`, while `MyClass` is a wrapper class for `DataRowView` that has to derive from some other type. `MyClass` keeps a reference to a `DataRowView`. Instead of binding `ComboBox.DataSource` to a `DataView`, I bind it to an `IList<MyClass>` but I still need the `ComboBox` to be able to access the `DataRowView` column values as if I was binding an `IList<DataRowView>`. Unfortunately the cast operator works the way I was afraid it would: it only takes into account compile time type information to do conversions (it does however use runtime type information when casting between types in the same inheritance tree).

Comment: Why don't you just create `MyType` with a function that returns an instance of `KnownType` built based on properties of the `MyType` instance? You could just then pass `myType.ToKnownType()` to the function that expects `KnownType`.

Comment: @xxbbcc He said he doesn't have control over the class doing the conversion.

Comment: It also depends on exactly what the code is doing to check the object you pass in. It may be explicitly checking that the object is the exact type, and even not one that is inherited from it.

Comment: @DavidG He posted the exact code that's being used, so we know it's not doing that.  (Not that it matters anyway.)

Comment: @Servy Well there may be additional code that is not shown.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I still don't understand why you can't pass the output of `ConvertToKnownType()` to the method that expects `object`? At the call site where you pass your current object, just pass `currentObject.ConvertToKnownType()` instead - you can clearly create an instance of `KnownType`, why don't you do that?

Comment: The code that does the conversion is not called directly from code I control. I will amend the question to provide more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  The cast provided would *only* succeed if you're able to derive your class from that class.  Any type of conversion not based on inheritance would require the class performing the conversion to do something different than what it's doing.

> Am I right to assume that the cast operator only works when the source type, target type and conversion operators are known at compile time?

Yes.

Comment: Note that if `KnownType` is an *interface* (or a type derived from `MarshalByRefObject`), you can trick the runtime into calling a custom conversion function by providing a transparent proxy as `parameter` (which you can obtain with a `RealProxy` implementation).